# How to c# function using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have input HTML button(Not ASP.NET Button) click event in c#

Is there any way i can call c# function using javascript

Thank you very much....

Comment: I figure I'll counter some of the downvotes with an upvote.  The question may be unclear, likely due to a language barrier, but what's being asked isn't really all that bad.  "I have a method in my C# code, I need to invoke it from JavaScript.  How?"  Simple.  Now, there may be more to this if the developer doesn't understand the disconnected nature of what's going on, but the central theme of the question is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest and most straightforward way will be to [create an HTTPHandler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) on your ASP .NET site and then your JavaScript can make an AJAX call ([easily](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) [done](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) [with](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) jQuery, note the three links to three different methods, and there are likely more) to invoke that handler at its configured URL.

Additionally, does this method need to return anything?  From the jQuery side your best bet will be to receive back a JSON object.  This can be done pretty easily from the .NET side with the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or even manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MS Ajax JS libs.  These will wire up things like that for you... but it has to be an ASP.NET button.  Sounds like you want to make an AJAX Service call.  Give us some more details as to how this is setup and how you want it to work.  ASP.NET Forms is not very forgiving to simple buttons and JS... you need to think about viewstate.